# Textures that aren't 16x16 fail to load in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, textures

```
public static int loadTexture(int resourceID) {
    int textureHandle[] = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if (textureHandle[0] != 0) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(SlingBall.context.getResources(), resourceID, options);

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, b, 0);

        b.recycle();
    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("RUFK");
    }

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

Here's my code for loading in a texture from resources.
This has worked fine for loading a 16x16 PNG file, but when trying to load anything that ISN'T 16x16 (smaller or bigger), it just turns out completely black.

I've tried creating several new PNG's, and yes, every single one that is 16x16 gets loaded properly.

This function gets called in onSurfaceCreated(), btw.

What is going on?

EDIT: Might as well add the shaders, not that I think it should be relevant, seeing as they work fine with 16x16.

VERTEX

```
uniform mat4 u_mvpMatrix;
attribute vec3 a_vertexPosition;
attribute vec2 a_texturePosition;

varying vec2 v_texturePosition;

void main() {
    v_texturePosition = a_texturePosition;
    gl_Position = u_mvpMatrix * vec4(a_vertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

FRAGMENT

```
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec2 v_texturePosition;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texturePosition);
}
```

(Its a lot more in reality, but I've taken it all out for debugging. Didn't make a difference tho. u_color isnt even used now)

VERTEX DATA

```
private static final float vertexData[] = {
            -1f, -1f, 0f,       0f, 0f,
            -1f, 1f, 0f,        0f, 1f,
            1f, -1f, 0f,        1f, 0f,
            1f, 1f, 0f,         1f, 1f
    };
```

3 for position, 2 for texture position.

I'm sorry if I'm not applying sufficient data, but I just have no clue where the problem is, and am just figuring it's probably something I'm doing wrong with the texture loading, since everything else works for 16x16. If there's anywhere you think the problem may lie in the code, please tell me so and I'll edit in the data.

Comment: It might be you need to have POT(power of two) textures meaning each of the dimensions has to be POT (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...) so 128x256 should be O.K. while 200x200 should not.

Comment: Yup, loading a 32x32 PNG worked.
Does it have to be like that? Can I change it? It seems awfully restrictive...

Comment: You may try to find something on the web for supporting a non POT textures but you will have a performance impact. Most people use texSubImage2D to fill a part of a texture, for instance to load a 100x100 texture you would use texImage2D with 128x128 dimensions and NULL data then use texSubImage2D to fill the 100x100 part. Note you will also need to correct the texture coordinates, instead of [.0, 1.0] they should be [.0, 100.0/128.0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using non-power-of-two (NPOT) texture, thing can get a little complicated. Excerpt from [OpenGL ES 2.0 Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) (section 3.8.2 pp.87-88):

```
Calling a sampler from a fragment shader will return (R; G; B; A) = 
(0; 0; 0; 1) if any of the following conditions are true:

...

- A two-dimensional sampler is called, the corresponding texture image is a
non-power-of-two image (as described in the Mipmapping discussion of
section 3.7.7), and either the texture wrap mode is not CLAMP_TO_EDGE, or
the miniﬁcation ﬁlter is neither NEAREST nor LINEAR.
```

So, make sure your texture wrap mode is `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` as well. Support for `REPEAT` and `MIRRORED_REPEAT` wrap modes are provided by the [OES_texture_npot](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_npot.txt) extension. It may be that your device doesn't support that extension.

Or you could just try to avoid using NPOT textures.